# How to change the selected tab on button click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have followed the tutorial found here:

[Implementing Fragment Tabs in Android](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/)

and I have it working properly, but I wanted to be able to switch the fragments on button click, not just on tab selection.  So inside of `FragmentTab1()` I have added an ImageButton that lets me switch out my fragments, and open `FragmentTab2()`.

This is the code inside of `FragmentTab1()` in `OnCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form1, container, false);
    btnFragment1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);

    btnFragment1.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);

    return rootView;
}
```

This is the code for my button:

```
Button.OnClickListener btnFragmentOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment newFragment;

        newFragment = new FragmentTab2();

        // Create new transaction
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }};
}
```

This works properly to switch out the fragments.

**My question is**: How do I get the selected tab to have the blue line underneath the text in the tab itself?
Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** I am not using a TabHost so this makes the solution trickier, I am using ActionBar.TabListener.

Answer (score 1):

adding these two lines did the trick inside of my button handler:

```
ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar)getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```